# What is the maximum value a single transaction output can have?

Tags: transactions

What is the largest amount one could send in a single transaction?

Also just to confirm my understanding, a transaction only has one destination address per transaction right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, transaction `amount` is of `mutez` type, which is internally represented by 64-bit signed integer.

However, in practice, (if we speak about applied transactions) the `amount` cannot exceed the total supply, wich is currently `873682204744114` (https://api.tzkt.io/v1/statistics/current).

And yes, a single transaction can have only one destination address.

Comment: ah okay thanks! so unlike bitcoin, the `amount` field doesn't have a fixed size e.g. 8 bytes?

Comment: oops, sorry, I confused `mutez` with `nat`. According to https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#type-mutez it's indeed 8-byte integer

Comment: is the maximum value is 9223372036854775807

Comment: @0x10, yes, according to the docs

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mean `amount` as transaction size and not as a `mutez` value.

The limits per transaction and block can be found in the following RPC: `/chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants`

[Edo Protocol](https://mainnet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants)

```
hard_gas_limit_per_block: "10400000"
hard_gas_limit_per_operation: "1040000"
hard_storage_limit_per_operation: "60000"
max_operation_data_length: 16384                 <---- CHANGED IN FLORENCE
```

[Florence Protocol](https://florencenet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/constants)

```
hard_gas_limit_per_block: "10400000"
hard_gas_limit_per_operation: "1040000"
hard_storage_limit_per_operation: "60000"
max_operation_data_length: 32768                 <---- CHANGED IN FLORENCE
```

> Also just to confirm my understanding, a transaction only has one destination address per transaction right?

Yes, but when calling a contract, it can also send internal transactions to other contracts.